# Получение коллекции из коллекций каждого объекта из коллекции этих объектов

Tags: java, java-stream

Решил все же таки попробовать Stream API - уж больно хорошо выглядит свернутый итератор в одну строчку. Столкнулся с вопросом, который пока что не в силах решить.

Есть `Collection<Obj1>`. В свою очередь, в `Obj1` есть поле `Collection<Obj2>`.

Возможно ли как-то стримом получить коллекцию `Obj2` из всех `Obj1`?
Или вообще получить `Collection<Obj3>`, используя `Obj2.getObj3()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей вам нужен [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
class Obj1 {
    List<Obj2> objects;

    public Obj1() {
        objects = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Obj1(List<Obj2> objects) {
        setObjects(objects);
    }

    public void setObjects(List<Obj2> objects) {
        this.objects = new ArrayList<>(objects);
    }

    public List<Obj2> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
}

List<Obj1> items = new ArrayList<>();
// Заполнение items экземплярами Obj1
// и заполнение их экземплярами Obj2

items
  .stream()
  .map(Obj1::getObjects)
  .flatMap(i -> i.stream())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```