# Как перевести Set<Set<Integer>> в Set<Integer> с помощью стримов?

Tags: java, java-stream

Дан `Set<Set<Integer>>`. Необходимо перевести его в `Set<Integer>`

```
Set<Set<Integer>> WinningLines = Set.of(Set.of(0, 1, 2), Set.of(3, 4, 5), Set.of(6, 7, 8), Set.of(9, 10, 11),
                    Set.of(12, 13, 14), Set.of(15, 16, 17), Set.of(18, 19, 20), Set.of(21, 22, 23),
                    Set.of(0, 9, 21), Set.of(3, 10, 18), Set.of(6, 11, 15), Set.of(1, 4, 7),
                    Set.of(16, 19, 22), Set.of(8, 12, 17), Set.of(5, 13, 20), Set.of(2, 14, 23));

Set<Integer> x = WinningLines.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Но нечего не получается, можете решить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что именно нужно сделать? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение коллекции из коллекций каждого объекта из коллекции этих объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683439/); [Превратить список из списков в стрим (на Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376466/); [Из Stream<List<Integer>> в List<Integer>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441985)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `flatMap` как раз подходит для такого преобразования. Он позволяет схлопнуть коллекцию из коллекций в одну «плоскую» коллекцию. Например, в случае с `Set`:

```java
Set<Set<Object>> setOfSets = ...
Set<Object> flatSet = setOfSets.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```